# Is it possible to provide a passwordless login via email (like Slack's magic log-in links) using AAD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to have the administrator of my app create users in Azure AD B2C and then have Azure AD B2C send a passwordless link to the user via email or pass me the link so that I can send it via email.  Is this possible via the existing service or API?

This article helps explain the concept using Auth0:
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/regular-web-app-email-link

Comment: Go vote for this feature https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334320-passwordless-authentication

Comment: @parsley72 - Just voted this up.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

I asked Swaroop Krishnamurthy (@swaroop_kmurthy) this same question via Twitter and received this response from him on 9/8/2016, "@keithdholloway this is on our roadmap but a bit further out than the near term."

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no support for this, developer must use AD B2C Policy for Authentication, always via a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I went to a meetup yesterday about Azure AD B2C Custom Policies. I asked the speaker if he knew if they could handle passwordless login, like entering your email address on an MFD then getting a popup on your mobile app to approve/deny but he wasn't sure. Later on he sent me [Azure Active Directory B2C: Custom CIAM User Journeys - Multi factor authentication enhancements](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#multi-factor-authentication-enhancements). From this it looks like [Azure AD B2C: TOTP multi-factor authentication](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp) may have some useful examples.